# How to retrieve data from mongoDB by date?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have data like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5ad47a26298e81149d2fef55"),
"modified" : ISODate("2018-04-16T10:25:42.135Z"),
"type" : "disconnect",
"agent" : ObjectId("59c4b036050de1829b7331e1"),
"time" : ISODate("2018-04-16T10:25:42.134Z"),
"created" : ISODate("2018-04-16T10:25:42.134Z")
```

How can i use find with date. I need to retrieve data based on "time" field. How do i write query?

Thanks

Comment: to interact with db you need serverside application, like nodejs, java, php etc

Comment: yes i am using nodejs.

Comment: i got data like this data { date: '2018-04-16', agent: '59c4b036050de1829b7331e1' }
and i tried this:   collection.find({
      agent: data.agent,
      time: { $gt: data.date }
    }) but if i pass date "2018-04-03" it also return the same result. exact date matching is not working